# Laravel fazer consulta em duas tabelas, não mostrando se id forem iguais

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho duas tabelas relacionadas no banco de dados: students e student_schedules.
Em determinado momento, quero listar todos os **students** que **NÃO** estejam em **student_schedules**.
Tentei fazer assim, mas não deu certo:

```
$schedules = StudentSchedule::all();
$students = Student::join('student_schedules', 'student_schedules.student_id', '!=', 'students.id')
                        ->select('student_schedules.student_id as idd', 'students.*')
                        ->get();
```

Na imagem ilustra bem oq preciso:
Quando houver o id de um student na tabela student_schedules, ele não aparece no select
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Será "Como mostrar dados que não estejam na tabela student_schedules?"

Comment: Amigo tenta o seguinte:

Comment: Se vc criou o relacionamento no model você pode usar doesntHave.
Student::doesntHave('nome_do_relacionamento_em_model')->get();
Mas só funciona se você definiu o relacionamento nome_do_relacionamento_em_model no model.

Comment: O SQL seria algo mais ou menos assim: `SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_id NOT IN (SELECT student_id FROM student_schedules);`, teria que converter para o ORM do Laravel

Comment: editei a pergunta pra ver se fica melhor de entender

Comment: Esses relacionamentos são chatinho mesmo tem que ficar testando, mas tenta assim ve se da certo, Students::leftJoin('students', 'students.id', '!=', 'student_schedules.student_id')->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite aos camaradas que me ajudaram, depois de tanto tentar conseguir usando o queries running do Laravel:

```
$students = DB::select('select * from students where id not in (select student_id from student_schedules where franchise_schedule_id = :id)', ['id' => $id]);
```

Obrigado a todos

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

$result = \DB::table('students')->whereNotIn('id', function($q){
    $q->select('student_id')->from('student_schedules');
})->get();

Comment: Fala amigo, só hj consegui mexer de novo nessa parada. Essa opção qs deu certo, porém preciso passar o id do franchise_schedule (->where('franchise_schedule_id', $id)), que recebo como parâmetro na url. se eu passo o id na mão, ele lista corretamente, mas se eu coloco o $id ele da um erro de Undefined variable: id
$students = DB::table('students')->whereNotIn('id', function($q){
            $q->select('student_id')
                ->from('student_schedules')
                ->where('franchise_schedule_id', $id)
                ->get(); 
        })
        ->get();

Comment: No seu where faltou o =
where('franchise_schedule_id', '=', $id)
Mas se você está dizendo que se colocar somente o numero da certo, então talvez seja o parâmetro da rota que eh o $id que não esteja vindo.

Comment: O estranho é q eu uso esse parâmetro nessa mesma função para buscar outros itens pelo $id